# ng-class not working in one situation. What are some possible cause of this?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm stuck. Cannot figured this out. This question is very simple to show, but I'm not really sure how to put it as a question, therefore I'll try my best.

First, here's the layout of my whole app (The problem lies in the Header.jsp):

```
<jsp:include page="../home/Header.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="../home/Modals.jsp" />
<div data-ng-view data-save-scroll-position data-position-relative-to-menu></div>
<jsp:include page="../home/Footer.jsp" />
```

The problem is very simple. I have the following `data-ng-class` in the `data-ng-view` section that change a tab to active if something is true (The problem is it won't work in one scenario even though it displayed `true` in the tab name):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" data-ng-class="tab.isSelected ? 'active' : ''" data-ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs" 
        data-ng-click="ctrl.fetchBIReports(tab)">
        <a href="" data-ng-bind="::tab.isSelected"></a>
    </li>                 
</ul>
```

In the JSP that use data-ng-include for the above markup, there's a side nav to change to this page. Once clicked this side-nav, it highlighted the tab `'active'` as expected (trying not to include the whole jsp):

```
<div class="side-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="{{ ctrl.navigate.path == 'bi/schedule' ? 'active-link' : 'normal-link'}}">
            <a href="#/bi" data-ng-click="ctrl.changeNavigation('bi/schedule')">Schedule Reports</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-right" data-ng-include="ctrl.navigate.path"></div>
```

`content-right` includes the JSP mentioned in the second markup.

So far, so good. Here's a demo of it working (including both `side-navbar` and `content-right`):

[image]

The problem is, in my Header.jsp, there's a nav bar that takes me to the same page. If it is clicked from a different page with different controller, then it works. But if I'm in the current controller and click that nav bar link, then data-ng-class does not take `'active'` as its class. Here's the markup for the Header.jsp for that link:

```
<li class="dropdown" data-roles="['ROLE_ADMIN']">
    <a href="#/bi" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-click="ctrl.changeNavigation('bi/schedule')" 
        role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">BI Management<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#/bi" data-ng-click="ctrl.changeNavigation('bi/schedule')">Schedule Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the demo of it not working even though it is printing out true in the UI:

[image]

The only problem is with this UI. All the data are populated. Records are displayed for the correct tab. Even side nav-bar is displaying the correct active class.

Comment: have you tried using ng-class instead? https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass. It sounds when clicking from the same page `ctrl.navigate.path` do not get updated. You can set a value on ng-click and use that value on `ng-class`

Comment: IMHO ng-class and data-ng-class are the same thing. :-)

Comment: Pretty sure they're the same, but I'm going to try anyway. The only thing data- does is remove the annoying yellow warnings. I don't want any of it in my project. Also, controller path always gets updated. I have the print out. It is called on onclick. You can see it in the sample code: `data-ng-click="ctrl.changeNavigation('bi/schedule')"`

Comment: Doesn't do anything as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for `ng-class` is off a bit. The format is "{ '[class-name]': [expression that evaluates to true or false] }". You can have multiple class values separated by commas each with their own expression. When an expression is true, the corresponding class is applied to the element and when it is false the class is removed from the element. The way you have written it would almost work for the plain `class` attribute, but you would need to include the interpolation characters: `{{` and `}}`. Here is a very simple example to illustrate `ng-class`.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```css
.red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e21d1d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="applyRedClass" /> Apply 'red' class
  </label>
  <div ng-class="{'red': applyRedClass}">
    This is a simple example of how to use ng-class.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this during my research for the fix and the behavior was the same. Therefore, I'm pretty sure both work exactly the same. I can do `data-ng-class="condition ? 'red blue yellow' : ''"` to add multiple classes as well.

Comment: Changed to `data-ng-class="{'active' : tab.isSelected}"` and it did nothing. You guys are just nitpicking on the small thing that has nothing to do with anything now. I think this is more of a controller instance problem (but I don't know why all the data are populated and changed except the class name). In the BI content page, it is the BIController that is changing the NavigationService's navigation path, while in the nav-menu, it is the NavigationController that is changing the NavigationService's navigation path. Does this provides any hints?